# installing aspnet_merge.exe on build machine without visual studio installed

Tags: asp.net, installation, aspnet-merge

The new aspnet_merge 5.00 beta is only installable from nugget.  to install on our build machine that doesn't have visual studio I want to use nugget.exe directly to get the package.

Anyone know if I can just replace the .EXE in the windows SDK ? I ask because in the SDK there is only the .exe but the beta came with more support files that I am unsure about.